# Is there a way to limit iPhone App to only certain models?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

We just finished building an iOS 8 app for the iPhone 5, 6, and 6 Plus.  It is limited it to iOS 8 and iPhone as shown below.

[image]

Unfortunately it got rejected because a button could not be accessed since it was offscreen.  We appealed immediately saying that it had been tested on the supported platforms.  That was submitted an hour ago.

If the App must support the iPhone 4s (Edited: I originally said 4) I would like to know so I can immediately submit a new build and get it in the queue instead of waiting for the appeal process.  If anyone has advice from a similar predicament I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should support any hardware platform that is capable of running the deployment target software. Fix it for the 4s and re-submit the new build ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 4s runs iOS 8. I would therefore assume Apple tested on an iPhone 4s.

The iPhone 4 does not support iOS 8 so that won't be a factor.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said 4s.  I assume that means I can't exclude the 4s?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. When Apple releases a new device it almost certainly releases an upgraded version of it's mobile OS and discontinues all the previous version of the OS. iPhone 4 is only compatible with iOS 7 I believe so you can't develop for iPhone 4 anymore. you get it?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said 4s.  I assume that means I can't exclude the 4s?

Answer (score -1):

well apple is releasing iOS 9 so I think 4s is irrelevant now

Comment: the 4s also supports iOS 9

Comment: The app supports iOS 8 and up to the 4s is still supported by the app.

Answer (score -1):

In iOS 10 the iPhone 4s is not supported anymore.

You will also lose some iPods and the original iPad.

http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/ios-10-supported-devices/

Comment: The app supports iOS 8 and up so the 4s is still supported by the app. Feel free to delete your answer.