# How to change my existing projects to work only for iphone?

Tags: ios

I am under on project.while submiting to app store they find some bugs while my app run in ipad.Now i need to change my existing projects to work only for iphone,ipod.How to do that?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

In your General Settings in Xcode, set it to iPhone only.

[image]

Click on Devices and select iPhone

[image]

Note that it will have to run on iPad in compatibility mode to be accepted to the App Store.  Compatibility mode is like a really big iPhone 4.

Comment: Thanks..initially i have made only for iphone.But they said its having some bugs while run in ipad...while they review our app.they will use iphone or ipad for testing

Comment: Yes, they use the iPad for testing.  We ran into the same problem when submitting our app (you can see the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621824/is-there-a-way-to-limit-iphone-app-to-only-certain-models) They will run it on an iPad to make sure it works even though it won't be shown in the iPad store.  That is because iPads are able to download iPhone apps and run them in compatibility mode.  Did you test it on the iPhone 4s and does it exhibit the same problems?

Comment: iPhone apps must run at iPhone4 resolution on an iPad.  If your app doesn't work correctly in this mode on an iPad it will be rejected

Comment: @dstudeba Yes ,but my app works fine in ios 8.While run my app in ipad for ios 9 .only one problem.my `my keyboard beginfirstresponder is not worked` .so they said user dont know what to do i this satge.Actually my keboard will shows up.but in ios 9 its does't work

Comment: Did you mean `becomefirstresponder`?

Comment: My guess is this is an iOS 9 issue, the only ones I have seen on that are because of the deprecated `UIAlertView`, but that was with the keyboard popping up unexpectedly.  Since they require you to run on a iPad you will have to go down that route unless you want to only launch on iOS 8.

Comment: @dstudeba sorry din't get you? can you explain me.now i need to work my app for ios 9 also.Now what should i do to rectify my problem to submit my aoo

Comment: Ask another question like "Keyboard become first responder not working in iOS 9 on iPad".  That is the problem that has to be fixed otherwise they won't let it in the app store.  Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098097/becomefirstresponder-not-working-in-ios-8

Comment: @dstudeba  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644137/keyboard-become-first-responder-not-working-in-ios-9-on-ipad....i have asked..