# iTunes Connect requiring 3.5-inch Screenshots for arm64 only App

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit an App that only supports arm64, which was developed in Xcode 7.  However, having uploaded the binary to iTunes Connect, it shows the following error message when I try to Submit:

> You must upload screenshots for 3.5-inch and 4-inch Retina displays., Your binary indicates support for iPhone/iPod touch. You must provide an iPhone/iPod touch screenshot.

I changed the Requirements in the Info.plist files, as well as the Architectures and Valid Architectures.  Is there something I am missing?  I only want to support 4+ inch displays and I believe you cannot have armv7s without armv7, so I only stipulated arm64.

**Update:**
In the end I just created separate Storyboard for the iPhone 4s and selected it in the View Controller programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you support iPhone you are going to have to support the 4 inch retina display.  Since iOS 9 is available for the iPhone 4s you need to support it.  I had the same problem: [Is there a way to limit iPhone App to only certain models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621824/is-there-a-way-to-limit-iphone-app-to-only-certain-models)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was under the illusion iOS 9 allowed arm64 only.  I suppose I'll have to create a layout for the 4s somehow.

Comment: You can still set your app to require only 64 bit if you use UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. Not sure if Apple allows a blank screenshot or not though.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your application, There's a number of reasons you might be recieiving that message.

1. Your app shows that it's supporting iPhone/iPod touch somewhere (plist, target build, etc.)
2. You have restricted the device requirements:

> Important: All device requirement changes must be made when you submit
>   an update to your binary. You are permitted only to expand your device
>   requirements. Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your
>   device requirements is not permitted. You are unable to restrict
>   device requirements because this action will keep customers who have
>   previously downloaded your app from running new updates.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Answer (score 0):

An additional reason this might be required, as I just discovered: When viewing an app on the App Store on a 4-inch device, it actually uses the 3.5-inch screenshots in the listing. Even when I called Apple's developer support, they didn't seem to understand this, then were surprised when they discovered it was true.