# Exclude iPhone 4S devices from downloading app

Tags: iphone, app-store, ios9, armv7

I will be releasing an app soon, but I specifically want to support iPhone 5 or later. Is there a way of excluding iPhone 4s devices? 
My app deployment target is iOS9, and iPhone 4S is the oldest device that can have iOS9, but because of screen size constraints I would prefer not to support those devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you are going to support iPhone you need to support all the iPhones that support the version of the operating system.  Apple will reject it for not supporting the 4S.  It is a pain, and I have been rejected for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Looks like I will have to work on supporting the 4S. It will be a pita..

Comment: Yup, been there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621824/is-there-a-way-to-limit-iphone-app-to-only-certain-models).  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If your app requires the Metal API, and that requirement is included in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities portion of the app plist, then that will prevent an iPhone 4S from downloading the app.

Comment: But also, you will exclude iPhone 5 and iPhone 5C. More info - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html